# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'IncomeTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, runtime-error

I set status of primary key in table to IDENTITY . I insert another fields of table in VS but when i run this program, the program has error. Why? What is my problem?

ID field in my table is set Identity.

The runtime error is:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'IncomeTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

in VS:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncomeTable income = new IncomeTable();
    income.amount_income = amount;
    income.comment_income = comment;
    income.date_income = date;
    context.IncomeTables.InsertOnSubmit(income);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I search but i cant solve this problem.
Cheers

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Yes . I using LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Open your table in visual designer
2. Click your column - Properties
3. Set `Auto Generated Value = True`
4. Set `Auto Sync = True`
5. Check the data type for that column if it's `Int NOT NULL IDENTITY`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I set Auto Generated Value to ture but i cant set Auto Sync to True. This value not allow for set. 'Server Data Type' for this column is 'Int NOT NULL' not Int NOT NULL IDENTITY.

Comment: Are you sure that column that caused the problem? which column in your table that have identity property and check the data type in table designer?

Comment: I'm not sure. The ID_Income column is identity. The data type of this column in table designer in VS is 'Type = int(System.Int32)' and 'Server Data Type = Int NOT NULL' that i change this type to 'Int NOT NULL IDENTITY'. my program runs but still has errors :( I'm confused. anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of these columns:

```
income.amount_income = amount;
income.comment_income = comment;
income.date_income = date;
```

is an identity column in the database. Check your table definitions and remove it.

Comment: none of these columns are not identity. I change parameters in ID column (in the above post) and my this problem solved .